# Adding text to a kivy file

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to make a text-based game for android using `kivy` and `kivymd`. I have to add a lot of text. The label command is the only command I know to add text. Is there an easier way to add text in a `kivy` program?

Answer (score 0):

No, Label is the only one widget for this.
You can check list of Widgets here:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.html